# Regex in url path param for express router

Tags: javascript, express

I have seen examples for regex being used in app.get in expressjs, but can someone confirm if router get works the same way? For example I am trying this, and it won't work

```
this.router.get('/myFolder/home/:id(/[0-9A-Za-z-\.@:%_\+~#=]+(\/(.)*)?(\\?(.)*)/)
```

Comment: Express uses this lib to match regex in routes: https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp , check there how to build routes with regexp for params.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I would test out something simpler to test it out and make sure it works.

Here is an article on the topic: https://www.kevinleary.net/regex-route-express/